# Integrating reCaptcha on Play 2.x Java

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, recaptcha

I am trying to implement reCaptcha on my java Play 2.4 web app.

I don't really know how to read the "g-recaptcha-response" after the captcha was sent.

Unfortunately all tutorials I could find for play 2.x where only for scala.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Can you please show a code sample of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your template, you can set `g-recaptcha-response` in a hidden form field :

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key" data-callback="captchaCallback"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="recaptcha" id="recaptcha" />

<script>
  function captchaCallback() {
    document.getElementById("recaptcha").value = document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").value;
  }
</script>
```

In your form validation you need to valdiate `recaptcha / g-recaptcha-response` value by request recaptcha API.

```
@Constraints.Required()
private String recapatcha;

private List<ValidationError> validate() {
  ...
  final JsonNode response = WS.url("recaptcha-verify-endpoint").setQueryParameter("secret", "your secret").setQueryParameter("response", this.recaptcha).post("").get(5000L).asJson();

  if(!response.get("success").booleanValue() && response.has("error-codes"){
    //TODO: Add error according to recaptcha error code
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! i wasnt aware of the data-callback